# Symfony2 UniqueEntity not working: throws db exception

Tags: php, symfony, unique-constraint

I have a User class as follows:

```
/**
* User
*
* @ORM\Table()
* @ORM\Entity
* @UniqueEntity("username")
*/
class User implements UserInterface
{
/**
* @var integer
*
* @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
* @ORM\Id
* @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
*/
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=30, unique=true)
 */
private $username;
...
```

As you guessed, I want to maintain usernames unique. When I try to register a new user which duplicates a previous username, I get a db exception:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO User (username, hashedpassword, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' with params ["xx", "$2y$10$7rrY0tw0eG8ui7hRkpGI..8Wf16DP1fQMLymaOmHnbZsBw6M1uY.i", "ddsds@u.com"]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'xx' for key 'UNIQ_2DA17977F85E0677'
```

I thought that perhaps the problem is in my Registration Controller. I'm using the one given on

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/registration_form.html

The relevant bits:

```
class AccountController extends Controller
{
public function registerAction()
{
    $registration = new Registration();
    $form = $this->createForm(new RegistrationType(), $registration, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('account_create'),
    ));

    return $this->render(
        'RezialRezialBundle:Account:register.html.twig',
        array('form' => $form->createView())
    );
}


public function createAction(Request $request)
{
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$form = $this->createForm(new RegistrationType(), new Registration());

$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isValid()) {
    $registration = $form->getData();

    //should I manually check for unicity here?


    $em->persist($registration->getUser());
    $em->flush();

    //The following 3 lines make the user automatically login
    //upon successfull registration!
    $user = $registration->getUser();
    $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, 'main', $user->getRoles());
    $this->get('security.token_storage')->setToken($token);

    return $this->redirectToRoute('homepage');
}

return $this->render(
    'RezialRezialBundle:Account:register.html.twig',
    array('form' => $form->createView())
);
}

}
```

Any ideas on what's missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Didn't you forget the *@Assert\Valid()* annotation on the $user property of the Registration class?

> This constraint is used to enable validation on objects that are
>   embedded as properties on an object being validated. This allows you
>   to validate an object and all sub-objects associated with it.

link: [Valid Constraint Documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Valid.html)

Comment: I had forgotten, just added it now. Yet, still the same db exception :(

Comment: AHH! Can't believe it. It works dude! First time I tried I type /* instead of /** for the first comment line. Apparently this does matter. lol. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="username", message="Username is already taken.")
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=30, unique=true)
     */
    protected $username;
}
```